# How to read war directory from a running JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, jetty, executable-jar, embedded-jetty

I am creating a standalone embedded jetty server. So basically I am providing a WebAppContext to my embedded jetty class so that it can read WEB-INF from a war directory and run the server. I packaged the project as a JAR and tried to run it from the command line. The JAR runs but the server requests do not go through (404 errors). The server runs perfectly when I execute it using maven command from inside Netbeans. So I guess it's not able to correctly locate resources when running the standalone JAR. I have tried adding the war folder a resource in the JAR file itself, hardcoded the local path and what not. Nothing seems to work right now. If someone has faced this problem and has a solution, I would be very thankful. 
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        String wardir = "webapps/war";
        //wardir = wardir.replace("//", "/");
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setResourceBase(wardir);
                String webXML = "/WEB-INF/web.xml";
               // webXML = webXML.replace("//", "/");
        context.setDescriptor(wardir + webXML);
        context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
                new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
                new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration() });

        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.dump(System.err);
        server.join();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you doing to set up this embedded-jetty scenario? (we need to see your code)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Added my code.